# Paypal call back give me 403 error: csrf token missing or incorrect on django app

Tags: django, paypal, csrf

I am implementing paypal to a django project. receiving a message to my notify_url works fine. but: when paypal tries to get back to my return_url I provided, django always says csrf-error and the page can not be displayed:

`403 error: csrf token missing or incorrect`

The return_url is directed to my start page. Any ideas whats wrong with it and why it throws this error?
I appreciate your help very much!
HA

EDIT
views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def view_back(request):
    return render_to_response("csrf.html",
                              {"csrftest":"here I am!" },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
url(r'csrf$', 'view_back', name='view_back')
```

csrf.html

```
<{% extends 'base.html' %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% block content %}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World</title>   
    </head>
    <body><h1>My Test</h1>
<!-- writes out the form tag automatically -->
{{ csrftest }}
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

EDIT2

```
urlpatterns = patterns('my_project.views',
    url(r'^$', 'calculation', name='calculation'),
    url(r'money$', 'view_that_asks_for_money', name='view_that_asks_for_money'),
    url(r'csrf$', 'view_back', name='view_back'),
)
```

Comment: Are you missing a csrf token? is it correct?

Comment: yes, this is what the 403 error tells to me. But how can I get this token from outside? Paypal can' t know it, isn't? Or can Paypal? And if yes: what do I have to do to get it to display my page with the return_url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using the `django-paypal` library but even if you are not this note from the documentation of the library explains everything:

> Note that return_url view needs @csrf_exempt applied to it, because
>   PayPal will POST to it, so it should be custom a view that doesn’t
>   need to handle POSTs otherwise.

So please careful when adding `@csrf_exempt`[[see the docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) to the view, make sure this page is used only for this purpose and not for other POSTs for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Hello Mauro, thank you for your reply. Yes, it is exactly this documentation. But to be honest: I do not understand what do to with it and how to imlement it. What I found so far is to put the @csrf_exempt in front of the definition. E. g. '@csrf_exempt', def view_that_asks_for_money(request). But this also does not work. Any working example for me to have a look at?

Comment: Hi, this must work, make sure that the view that is called when you visit return_url has the decorator not the view that sends the request to paypal.

Comment: Hi Mauro, see an edit above what I did. I still get the error: CSRF token missing or incorrect. What is my mistake?

Comment: You sure your are landing on the correct view ? you created an empty app fot test or you have other urls in your urls.py

Comment: the returning url tries to open csrf.html, this is what I see in the browser. within the urls.py are 2 other urls which lead to 2 other views in the same views.py but with. but the url is different. Am I not allowed to have other urls in the urls.py of this app? does I have to create a new app only to see this view?

Comment: Hi, I was just thinking that by mistake you could have a catch all url like '^/'. Comment out the other urls or post them to make sure is not the case.

Comment: Hi Mauro, I added the urls.py in EDIT2.

Comment: How are you testing this view ? You are calling with POST method with tools like POSTMAN ?

Comment: testing with ngrok. notify_url works fine and I get back the status from paypal. but the redirect_url makes trouble with this csrf_token..

Comment: This is becoming a chat, moderators will not be happy. Anyway where redirect_url is pointing ?

Comment: to url(r'csrf$', 'view_back', name='view_back') and the csrf.html

Comment: So, if you call directly the url with a tool like Postman or whatever rest test tool with method POST you get the error ?

Comment: no, when directly calling with ngrok than I get the page. but when coming via paypal's sandbox than I get the error.

Comment: So if you call the view with method POST you don't get any error ? If this is true than the decorator is working as expected and when Paypal makes the call should just work the same way.

Comment: what I do is calling the url directly. my localhost:8000 gets a tunnel via ngrok and calling http:///myinternetadressviatunnel.com/csrf delivers the page csfr.html to the browser. but calling exactly the same adresse when paypal comes back to my page brings this error up.

Comment: If you are it calling just with the browser you do a GET request and not a POST. Simulate a POST please https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: when posting via ngrok I get a 403 Forbidden, the post goes to /csrf

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I just created a sample app with your exact code and all works. Are you using class based view ? Can you post your views.py

Comment: Mauro! I think I have it! I added the language to the receiver_url, it was: http://myinternetadressviatunnel.de/de/csrf but it seems it has to be http://myinternetadressviatunnel.de/csrf without the language. I am wondering why this is the reason for the problem. I keep on testing it the verify that I resolved it. Anyway: I will come back to you with a feedback. What really gave me a excellent hint from your side: to use the csrf_exempt only for the view pointing to the return_url! Thank you so far!!

Comment: Well, than mark my answer as correct and the problem with the language is that if you don't have django configured well the url with de will not go to the same view. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#url-internationalization

Comment: Thanks again. everything is working fine. I checked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 4):

I have a slightly different answer for this question, as I was trying to figure out how to do this with Express Checkout/Server Integration, and the answer is as follows:

```
paypal.Button.render({
    env: 'sandbox',
    client: {
        sandbox: 'sandbox-client-id',
        production: 'live-client-id'
    },
    payment: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.request({
            method: "post",
            url: '/your/django/payment/route/',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
            },
            json: {
                key: value,
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.id;
        });
    },
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.request({
            method: "post",
            url: '/your/django/execution/route/',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
            },
            json: {
                payment_id: data.paymentID,
                payer_id: data.payerID,
                key: value,
            }
       })
       .then(function(response) {
            // Show the buyer a confirmation message.
            return console.log(response);
       });
    }
}, element_selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to pass CSRF with paypal, to a django backend.

payment: function () {

```
    return new paypal.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '{% url 'payment_comms' %}',
        data: {
          what: 'create_payment',
          amount: $("#amount").val(),
        },
        headers: {
          'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
        },
        success: function (data) {
          resolve(data.paymentID);
        },
        error: function (data) {
          reject(data)
        }
      })
    })
  },
```